# Изменение переменных в разных потоках (volatile)

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, меня интересует модификатор `volatile` я не до конца понимаю его смысл применения, поможет ли он мне оптимизировать работу программы, если в нескольких потоках идет изменение нескольких переменных и следственно вывод на GUI

Comment: Оптимизировать по сравнению с мьютексами? По идее да.

Comment: @VladD да, с мьютексами или `lock`

Comment: Если у вас идёт вывод в UI, заметной разницы не ждите: вывод занимает куда больше времени, чем взятие мьютекса / барьер памяти, который происходит при обращении к volatile-переменной.

Comment: @VladD т.е другими словами, смысла большого использовать `valotile` нет

Comment: Но зато есть смысл минимизировать участки, находящиеся под lock’ом, возможно до просто чтения в локальную переменную или записи из неё

Comment: Волатильность влияет на оптимизации на самом низком уровне, никакой потокобезопасности она не дает, и не является, примитивом синхронизации. Она скорее дает эффект при работе с атомарными операциями (атомарная операция априори потокобезопасная) с нескольких ядер и гарантирует, что инструкции процессора будут им выполнены в том порядке, в котором задумано, но за это придется заплатить отсутствием некоторых оптимизаций. В общем, это не то, что вы думаете.

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile).

Comment: Например в одном потоке вы поменяли значение поля, следом в другом потоке его прочитали, и если поле не волатильное, то есть шанс, что ядро прочитает свой кеш вместо обращения к реальному новому значению переменной. И работает это только с атомарными операциями. На неатомарные операции наличие или отсутствие волатильности не влияет, так как потокобезопасность таких операций должна обеспечиваться блокирующими примитивами синхронизации или интерлоком.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, теперь понял)

Comment: @aepot т.е. volatile форсирует синхронизацию между уровнями кэша проца для нескольких ядер и озу для переменной размером не более 32 бит? Или нет никакой синхронизации и данные всегда берутся из ОЗУ / пишутся в ОЗУ?

Comment: @Blackmeser нет, почитайте доку, там пример. Что касается озу, не все переменные туда вообще в принципе попадают.